# What is the minimum number of shards required for Mongo database to store 1 billion documents?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, database-performance, sharding

We need to store **1 billion** documents of 1KB each. Each shard is planned to have 8GB of RAM. The platform is Open Shift Red Hat Linux.

Initially **we had 10 shards for 300 million**. We started inserting documents with 2000 inserts/second. Everything went well till 250 million. After that the insert slowed down drastically to **300/400 insert** per second.

The queries are also taking long time (more than 1 minute) even all the queries are covered queries.(Queries which need to scan all the indexes).

Hence we assumed, that 20 million per shard is the optimal value and hence we require 50 shards for the current hardware to achieve 1 billion.

Is this reasonable estimate or we can improve it (less shards) by tweaking mongo db parameters for better performance with the current hardware?

There are two compound indexes and one unique index(long).insertion is done using bulk write( with unordered option) with 10 threads and 200 records per (thread) bulk write using java script directly on the mongos.Shardkey is nodeId(prefix of compound index) which has cardinality upto 10k. For 300 million, the total index size comes to 45 GB.40 GB for the 2 compound indexes.Almost 9500 chunks are distributed across 10 nodes.One interesting fact is that if I increase RAM to 12 GB, the speed increases to 1500 inserts/sec.Is RAM limiting factor?

**Update:**

Using mongostat tool, we found that the flush(fysnc) takes more than 55 seconds to complete.MongoDB cluster runs on kubernetes based on RedHat OpenShift platform. It runs on Dell EMC server with NFS (EXT4 disk format).Is it a problem in the I/O that it supports only 2MB/second. It takes 60 seconds to write 2000 records per second and another 55 seconds to flush completely to disk.(during which all the operations of DB are blocked)
The disk utilization does not even reach 4 %.

Comment: There's not really enough information here.  If it was truly a covered query and still took over a minute, that must be one enormous index.

Comment: I think it is more important how you insert the data, how you model it, the shard key, which indexes and the query. In my application I insert up to 80000 documents per second (5 billion doc per day) with only 4 shards.

Comment: There are two compound indexes and one unique index(long).insertion is done using bulk write( with unordered option) with 10 threads and 200 records per (thread) bulk write using java script directly on the mongos.Shardkey is nodeId which has cardinality upto 10k. For 300 million, the total index size comes to 45 GB.40 GB for the 2 compound indexes.Almost 9500 chunks are distributed across 10 nodes.One interesting fact is that if I increase RAM to 12 GB, the speed increases to 1500 inserts/sec.Is RAM limiting factor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not sharding at all?

There's a common tendency to shard prematurely. I've seen a MongoDB consultant who suggested a rule of thumb, to not shard until your total data size is at least 2 TB. Your 1B documents of 1KB each should be around 1 TB. While it's only a rule of thumb, maybe it's worth trying.

If nothing else, it'll be much simpler to design the db without sharding and performance will be much more predictable.

Comment: Initially we tried without sharding then increased to 3, then increased to 10 and now we finally increased to 25. The reason for sharding was latency in queries. Some queries were taking too long time where the entire index need to be scanned. (sorting with other than prefix of compound index)

Comment: I just noticed that your server is at < 12 GB RAM. This seems very low based on your collection and index size. It's possible sharding will help (this is outside my experience), but it's very possible you just needed to throw a little more hardware at this. Data's hard to compare apples to apples, but just as one anecdote, I run a 300 GB MongoDB server with about 120 GB RAM which our MongoDB consultant said was undersized if anything. I think MongoDB may be pretty memory hungry. You should at least make sure your total index size is less than available RAM, see if that helps!

Comment: Here's some useful documentation about index size relative to available RAM: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Comment: 25 shards each 8 GB RAM . 200 GB RAM in total. Is this not enough ? Index size is only 45 GB.

Comment: If the entire index is being scanned to support a sort, doesn't that imply that all of the documents are also being loaded into memory to apply filtering?

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense on the RAM. Did you have 200 GB total RAM when only using a single shard, too?

Comment: How long it took for shard at these scale @MuraliMohanMurthyPotham